# Monthly categories with MySQL DATE Type

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm building a mini news CMS where the news added are sorted using a DATE type column e.g. `INSERT date_posted=NOW()`, etc.

I can then easily list out all the available months with: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_posted, '%M %Y') as date_posted`. This makes the monthly categories list.

The issue I'm having is with *displaying* all the news by a particular month. I have tried to pass the date_posted variable in the URL but have failed to actually incorporate it in my Query. If for instance, I try `WHERE date_posted=\"2009-10-16\"`, the result is all the news of that day. `WHERE date_posted=\"2009-10\"` doesn't work on the other hand.

I've passed this parameter in the URL `DATE_FORMAT(date_posted, '%M%Y') as month` which echos out October2009 for example. Then WHERE date_posted=$month returns nothing because firstly I'm guessing it's in the wrong format, secondly, the MySQL data type does not output what I want as evidenced by the aforementioned hard-coded example.

Please help,
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a range in your `where` clause:

```
where   date_posted >= cast('2009-10-01' as date)
    and date_posted <  cast('2009-11-01' as date)
```

To get the "2009-10-01" and "2009-11-01" dates, you can use PHP's [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions:

```
$date_from_querystring = "2009-10";
$start_date = $date_from_querystring . "-01";
$end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date . " +1 month"));
```

You could also use the `year` and `month` functions, but then you won't get any benefit from any indexes you might be able to use, so it's generally not as good a solution as the range.  An example:

```
where year(date_posted) = 2009 and month(date_posted) = 10
```

Comment: That's great but I get lost at the actual "category" part. For instance, how would I dynamically change those two for each subsequent month like October 2009 gets that, obviously but how would it change for January 2010?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the year and month ones would work. Just that the $month=october2009 string would have to be dissected to be able to do so where the function used would be...? :D

Comment: Awesome! So it came out to date('Y-m', strtotime($month));

Thank you very much for your kind help, Sir! I had been trying to do this on my own for the last 7 hours but finally gave up and asked here. Really appreciate your help! :)